# Can a `return` return a `break` in C?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I just want to do something like this:

```
int moduleDecision(int ModuleSelect)
{
    if (ModuleSelect == Nmodules)
    {
        ModuleSelect == 0x00;
        return (break);
    }
    else
    {
        ModuleSelect = ModuleSelect + 0x01;
        return ModuleSelect;
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function inside a larger `switch`, so I want to be able to exit the switch if `ModuleSelect == 0x00`.

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Precisely what value do you suggest `break` would have as the function result? (and... *no*, that isn't how the language works).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `break` is a statement, not an expression. It has no value. It is certainly not an `int`. This code would fail to compile.

One thing you might be able to do is to designate a particular value to return for your special case. In the calling code, test for that value and `break` there.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. But in the calling function you can check the returned value, and if it's zero (for example) then you do a `break` statement.

Answer (score 2):

No. A "break" is not an int, so it cannot be returned by your function.

If 0 is a special value, why not use that as a case within your switch statement? Just return 0 or another special value and process accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the function only in one place in your code, you can replace the call with the actual code and then the break works as usual.